# Jekyll not refreshing changes to custom CSS Subdirectory

Tags: sass, gulp, jekyll

For work I have to manage styles and keep them consistent between two different sites. To accomplish this, I created a repository where I can use gulp/scss to export the CSS I need. **Changing this is not an available option for me.**

One of the sites is built using Jekyll. I have cloned the CSS directory and pointed the CSS to pull from that directory, no problem. When I make changes to the scss, the gulp task exports the CSS, but the changes are reflected when I am running the site. It detects the changes and says it regenerates the file, but the CSS simply doesn't get updated. If I stop the Jekyll process and re-run `bundle exec jekyll serve` - the css changes immediately show up.

Basically, I just want to know if there is a way to make sure these files get updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but can you give a little more infos about your process. Who's watching ? Repositories architecture ? Repositories urls ?

Comment: I figured out that for some reason, Jekyll is only ignoring the scss changes to files with underscores, so `_nav.scss` for example. That at least got me working. Now, I just need to determine if it is a problem with my config file or just a general incompatibility.